# Connect Database to Drupal Pages

Tags: database, drupal

Is there a way to connect a number in a database to a page in the Drupal environment? I am trying to connect zip codes and postal codes to pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new content type and mass import your zip and postal codes via Feeds Importer. If you need a node to be the zip or postal code, set the "Title" to hold the zip or postal code. Or, create a View that will display the zip or postal codes as desired.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create node template first search how to create it.
and then you can write query to database in node template file and fetch every think you need in node page. GOOD LUCK